# Как реализовать в TransparentProxy дополнительные интерфейсы?

Tags: c#, proxy, .net-remoting

Я разбираюсь с тем, как писать прокси, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Объявление класса прокси:

```
public class TestProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    public TestProxy() : base(typeof(T)) { }
/* ... */
}
```

Дальше я перекрываю в нём метод `Invoke`, возвращаю оттуда объект класса `ReturnMessage`, там всё понятно и удобно.

Использование прокси:

```
ICaller caller = (ICaller)(new TestProxy<ICaller>()).GetTransparentProxy();
```

После этого я могу вызывать методы интерфейса `ICaller`, всё работает адекватно.

Но дальше мне нужно, чтобы полученный TransparentProxy мог реализовывать интерфейсы, отличные от того, который я передал в качестве generic-параметра классу `TestProxy`. В данном случае, не только `ICaller`. По идее, метод `GetTransparentProxy` виртуальный, и, наверное, надо что-то сделать при его переопределении. Но в документации у Microsoft не сказано, как его правильно переопределять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порылся рефлектором в стандартной библиотеке и быстро нашёл ответ сам. Чтобы реализовать желаемое поведение, необходимо реализовать в классе прокси интерфейс `System.Runtime.Remoting.IRemotingTypeInfo` и в методе `CanCastTo` проверять, какой интерфейс запрошен, через первый параметр. Также там можно увидеть, что в стандартной библиотеке метод `GetTransparentProxy` не переопределён ни в том прокси, который используется в .NET Remoting, ни в том прокси, который используется в WCF.